# Sitecore 9.0 Dynamic Placeholders in WebForms

Tags: dynamic-placeholder, webforms

I've got a Sitecore 9.0.2 site that will migrate from WebForms to MVC in the near future.  First, we are componentizing the site and are building reusable components for a Two-Column container.

The question is:

Does the OOTB dynamic placeholder functionality for Sitecore 9 support WebForms?  The documentation only has examples for MVC:

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/dynamic-placeholders.html

Comment: you can find this here - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3531/form-dynamic-placeholder-use, also there is module supported till Sitecore 8 - https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/I/Integrated_Dynamic_Placeholders.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No, the OOTB Dynamic Placeholders in Sitecore 9+ does not support Webforms. The implementation is in the **Sitecore.Mvc** namespace, a.k.a. this is an MVC-only implementation.

If you need to support Webforms then you would need to fallback to rolling your own or using one of the community implementations (such as [Fortis Dynamic Placeholders](http://fortis.ws/fortis-collection/dynamic-placeholders/)), but you may need to update them to be compatible with Sitecore 9+.